# String Concatination in println() method

Tags: java, arrays, string

- println() method while printing it adds the values in case of array also

  ```
  int a = 5;
  int b = 3;
  int c[] = {1,2};
  System.out.println(a+b);            //8
  System.out.println(a+b+" ");        //8
  System.out.println(c[0]+c[1]);      //3
  System.out.println(c[0]+c[1]+" ");  //3
  ```

why it gives different results ?

Comment: The code you've posted(with `a[]` changed to `a1[]`) gives the output, `8, 8, 3, 3`. How exactly did you get `8, 5 3, 3, 3`? Can you explain a bit more? [FYI, Proof](https://ideone.com/inL7Wp).

Comment: Because `+` is ambiguous in these cases. Avoid this ambiguity and you're done.

Comment: Your description is wrong!!! `System.out.println(a+b+" ");` prints `8`, followed by a space character. You probably meant `System.out.println(a+" "+b);`.

Comment: What is the issue,you are getting correct answer.Also in place of 5 3 output will be 8

Comment: Now you've changed the description, and left the question without any point in it ("why it gives different results?" - the results are **NOT** different anymore)!

Comment: The println() method doesn't concatenate anything. It takes a single String argument. The concatenation is done automatically by the + operator, before println() is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java when you add variable of any datatype (int,float,double) using  "+" operator with string whether it may be " " also, variables of other datatypes will also be implicitly get converted to String and all get appended instead of adding.

```
In first case a+b: 
both are integers, so it directly adds up to give 8.

In second case a+b+ " ":
first two operands are integers it adds up to give 8 but since third one is a string 
(" ")
it i.e. 8 gets converted to "8" then get concatenated with " " i.e. "8"+" " to give 8

  In third case c[0]+c[1] : 
  Here both are integers so 1+2 = 3

  In fourth case c[0]+c[1]+ " " :
 Here first two integers added to give 1+2 = 3 but since third is a string so 3 gets    converted to "3" and gets concatenated to "3" + " " to give 3

  But if below is the case: 
  i.e. 
  System.out.println(" " + a+b);
  Then answer would be 53. 
  Because: First operand is string so, both 5 and 3 get converted to "5" and "3" and     concatenate with " " to give " "+"5"+"3"= 53
```

Comment: **Thank You** coming to my problem while printing **array** elements using index values `a[0]+a[1] = it gives addition value;` `a[0]+a[1]+" " = it gives same addition value;` **Its my Doubt** _WHY?_

Comment: because of precedence. Since it evaluates from left to right, first addition happens then conatenation. So it is.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `System.out.println` can take an `int` as an argument.

This means any `int` value (e.g. `int` sums not prepended by a `String`, even empty) will print evaluated expression.

Secondly, your second `println` statement will actually print:

```
8
```

(notice the space after)

... provided you don't declare `array` `a` of course.

Finally, to print `array` contents, use:

```
int[] a = {1,2};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2]
```

Comment: **Thank You** coming to my problem while printing **array** elements using index values `a[0]+a[1] = it gives addition value;` `a[0]+a[1]+" " = it gives same addition value;` **Its my Doubt** _WHY?_

Comment: @CHAITHANYAPADALA because in your second case, although a `String` is given as argument (since you concatenate with empty `String`), the `int` operation is evaluated first (from left to right).

Answer (score 0):

Your description for `System.out.println(a+b+" ")` printing `5 3` is wrong!

You probably meant `System.out.println(a+" "+b)` which indeed prints `5 3`.

Having said that, here is the proper "interpretation" of each `println` statement:

---

```
System.out.println(a+b);
System.out.println(5+3);
System.out.println(8);
```

---

```
System.out.println(a+" "+b);
System.out.println(5+" "+3);
System.out.println("5 "+3);
System.out.println("5 3");
```

---

```
System.out.println(c[0]+c[1]);
System.out.println(1+2);
System.out.println(3);
```

---

```
System.out.println(c[0]+c[1]+" ");
System.out.println(1+2+" ");
System.out.println(3+" ");
System.out.println("3 ");
```

Comment: **Thank You** Clear explanation

Comment: You're welcome... But I noticed that you've changed the description, and left the question without any point in it ("why does it give different results?" - the results are **NOT** different anymore)!

Answer (score 0):

"+" operator behaves differently for different types. For integer values it sums the arguments  (like 1+1 gives 2) and for string values it concatenates them (like "1"+"1" gives "11"). In your question you probably meant to concatenate them, so you have to convert them to String first.

However, what I would suggest you is using StringBuilder for String concatenation, like that:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 3;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
System.out.println(sb.append(a+b).toString()); // 8

sb = new StringBuilder();
System.out.println(sb.append(a).append(b).toString()); // 53

sb = new StringBuilder();
System.out.println(sb.append(a).append(" ").append(b).toString()); // 5 3

// ... and so on.
```